# Use of super vs. this in cases of no override

Tags: java

I'm currently taking an intro level CS course at my university. My professor insists on using `this.method()` rather than `super.method()`.

Example: I'm calling a method from a superclass, `getOneIntersectingObject()`, and since it's in the superclass I usually call it by using `super.getOneIntersectingObject()`. However, my professor wants me to call it using `this.getOneIntersectingObject()`.

I understand that `this` searches the current class and executes its `method()` over any similarly named `method()` in any superclasses, but my question is this:

Why use `this` if you're not overriding the method? Is this just common programming etiquette?

Comment: Can you show some actual code here?  `this.method()` is different than `super.method()`, and two don't necessarily stand in juxtaposition to each other.

Comment: Although `this.method()` is always redundant.

Comment: @chrylis not *always*, just often.

Comment: Using `super.method()` is the exceptional case. You certainly shouldn't be using it out of habit to refer to a method in the current class.

Comment: It is good practice to use `this` when referencing a member variable.  It conveys intent and prevents conflicts between local variables of the same name.

Comment: `super.method()` means "I want to call this method on the current object, but I want to go around whatever is in *this* class and get the implementation defined in my superclass". Unless you're in that situation, there's no reason to write `super.method()`, and you're code will be very confusing if you do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why use `this` if you're not overriding the method?

Because

- It's less complicated to use `this` consistently rather than using `this` or `super` depending on what method you're calling.
- You may add an override later; using `super` would require that you go back and fix all of the places you called it.
- And yes, because it's the normal thing to do.

This is a CW, anyone else who wants to jump in with reasons, please don't hesitate.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use `this` or `super` if you don't use an override. If you have an override, `this.method()` calls the method of the child class (derived class) and `super.method()` calls the method of parent class. `super.method()` is like saying, "i want parent class's method() to execute, not the child's".